# Android Studio иконки состояния ветвей

Tags: android-studio, git

подскажите пожалуйста, раньше в андирод-студии в окне Git Branches были иконки состояния ветки локального репозитория, по отношению к удаленному (для каждой ветки в списке). После какого-то обновления AS они исчезли и иконка стала отображаться только для активной ветки. Можно ли как-то вернуть отображение состояния для **всех** веток?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]